# changes in local index.js file not getting reflected in bot

Tags: dialogflow-es, webhooks, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have written a local index.js file and hosted through google cloud sdk. updated webhook of dialogflow. It is working fine. But when i make some changes in local index.js these changes are not getting reflected in bot replies.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer we can just edit the source code of the deployed function through google cloud platform and deploy it again